# Tinymce editor set new line when word is too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, editor

I have tinymce editor. Have problem that if there is text like 'Hello, some text.... leadname'
and 'leadname' is one word but there is no enough space for show on one line , so tinymce shows part of word on first line, and other part on second. I hoped that it is possible to parse content and put

tags if necessary. It is my code:

```
            editor.on('input', function (e) {
            var editorWidth = editor.getBody().clientWidth; // get editor width in pixels
            var avgCharWidth = 8.5; //average character width
            var maxLineLength = Math.floor(editorWidth / avgCharWidth); // calculate max characters per line
            // Split the text into words using a regular expression
            var words = editor.getContent({ format: 'text' }).match(/\S+\s*/g);

            // Iterate over the words and add newlines as necessary
            var newText = '';
            var lineLength = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                var word = words[i];
                // Check if the word fits on the current line
                if (lineLength + word.length <= maxLineLength) {
                    // Add the word to the current line
                    newText += word;
                    lineLength += word.length;
                } else {
                    // Add a newline before the word
                    newText += '<p>' + word;
                    lineLength = word.length;
                }
            }

            // Add a closing tag to the last paragraph
            newText += '</p>';

            // Set the new text in the editor
            editor.setContent(newText);

            // get all Textnodes from lastchild, calc length
            let textnodes = getTextNodes(editor.getBody().lastChild);
            // set Cursor to last position
            editor.selection.setCursorLocation(textnodes[textnodes.length-1], textnodes[textnodes.length-1].textContent.length );
        });
```

But it doesnt work always good. Sometimes it adds new line early and then when i try remove symbols, other lines breaks. So something is wrong and cant understand what.
Also if click 'enter' it will no work.
Maybe there is solution without parse content?
Thanks.

Comment: no ideas how do it?(